# Including call to drupal_get_form('user_login') causes seemingly endless loop in Firefox

Tags: 7, hooks, users

One of the features that I've tried to include in my Drupal site is a persistent login form in the page's footer. After doing some searching around, I found that the best way to call the login in Drupal 7 is the following:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login'));
```

So, I put this in a simple if/then statement that looks like this:

```
<?php    
global $user;

    if ( $user->uid ) {
        echo "<a href='admin/' target='_blank'>Go to Admin area</a>.";  
    }
    else {
        print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login')); 
    }
?>
```

I then tucked this away in a jQuery accordion, and it was working just wonderfully in Chrome.

Then came Firefox. It loaded fine the first time, but then once I clicked on the accordion to view the login, it never loaded correctly again. I know that this is the culprit, because once commented out, the page loads fine in Firefox. Am I doing this call wrong?

Comment: N.B. I've even tried using the traditional login block, and I get the same endless looping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working. After debugging, Firefox (and my mountains of code) was having an issue with the core module OpenID. I assume that since it only recently became an issue that it's a particular problem for my particular framework.